# C# compiler error CS1628 with VS2010/C#4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compiler-errors

This compiler error is listed in the C# compiler errors on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we3011f5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for VS2005 and VS2008, but not for newer versions.

This would make me assume the error is not applicable or fixed for newer versions of the compiler, but this appears to not be the case.

I have also noted the list of compiler errors is substantially [less](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for Visual Studio versions 2010 and above.

Am I correct?

Comment: Looks like an accidental omission. Unfortunately my spy, I mean former colleague, on the MSDN C# documentation team just retired, so I don't have a back channel to report these things anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This error still happens on VS2012 (and this is due to a conceptual limitation around delegates and ref parameters, not a technological limitation). I'm guessing the documentation just hasn't been updated...

Comment: After some thinking, I think this is a technological limitation. `ref` parameters are handled differently from locals and it would be impossible to capture a `ref` parameter for assignment in a closure. IMO, it would involve some serious compiler magic to get this working in a reliable way. The other alternative would be to implement `ref` parameters as boxes, but that would be a significant change in the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error with VS2022 so no, you're not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).