# What does implementing "ref parameters as boxes" mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clr

I was recently reading an answer about CS1628, "Cannot use ref or out parameter 'parameter' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression".

The answer stated a way around this is to implement "ref parameters as boxes" in the CLR.

[C# compiler error CS1628 with VS2010/C#4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733552/c-sharp-compiler-error-cs1628-with-vs2010-c4)

I am unsure what this means and seem to be unable to find any references to it in google.

Can anyone please explain this to me as its way over my head?

Comment: The user was talking about what C# as a language could have done (but didn't do) to enable this feature.  He wasn't talking about how you would work around the lack of the feature.

Comment: There is no work around for this - the comment is talking about a ways to change the compiler and/or CLR to make it possible.

Comment: Sorry if I perhaps wasn't clear enough, I understand that the user was talking about what they could have done in terms of the language, I am more getting at what are boxes he is referring to in the CLR?

Comment: Basically you create a custom object that wraps or "boxes" the value that you want to pass. See usr's answer for more implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a "box" class:

```
class Box<T> { public T Value; }
```

Pass an instance of that class to the method that you cannot use `ref` with. The method can reach into the object and mutate `Value`. The caller can later extract `Value`.

This works (in constrast to ref) because `Box` is allocated on the heap and has "infinite" lifetime. `ref` can only refer to locations with more restricted lifetime.